# Accessing property in an object

Tags: javascript

Consider this code snippet

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this._elem = 5;
  }

  get elem() {
    return this._elem;
  }
}

class B {
  constructor() {
    this._elem = 6;
  }
}

class C extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

class D {
  constructor() {}
}

const a = new A();
const b = new B();
const c = new C();
const d = new D();

function foo(obj, name) {
  const val = 'elem' in obj ? obj.elem : 42;
  const val2 = obj.elem ? obj.elem : 42;
  console.log(`For ${name} val: ${val}, val2: ${val2}`);
}

foo(a, 'a');
foo(b, 'b');
foo(c, 'c');
foo(d, 'd');
```

I was trying to figure out if there ever could be a case where directly using `obj.elem` when the property `elem` doesn't exist on `obj` could lead to incorrect logic vis-à-vis doing a check for `"elem" in obj` and access it only if it exists and use the value. It seems like `val` and `val2` would always be the same. Are both equivalent?

Comment: If the `elem` getter would return 0 or `false` or the empty string or `NaN` or `undefined` or `null`,... the ternary expression would go the wrong way.

Comment: if `obj.elem = 0` then you'd get `val = 0` and `val2 = 42`. Same with any other falsy value like empty string or `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent, and this is because `obj.elem ? obj.elem : 42` will execute the getter and see if its return value is truthy or falsy. If it happens to be falsy, then this expression will evaluate to 42. Yet, `"elem" in obj` is true independent on whether the method would return a falsy or truthy value.

Unrelated, but it is also not efficient, as `obj.elem ? obj.elem : 42` will execute the getter *twice* when it returns a truthy value.